# Spring jdbc Transaction issue

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

dao layer abstraction

```
interface DaoLayer {
   Long createFavouriteWidgetInfo(FavouriteWidgetInfo favouriteWidget);
}
```

dao Layer Implementation

```
class DaoLayerImpl implements DaoLayer
     @Transactional
     @Override
    public Long createFavouriteWidgetInfo(FavouriteWidgetInfo favouriteWidget) {
        Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Long val= (Long) session.save(favouriteWidget);
        throw new NullPointerException();
        //return val;
    }
```

Sample Test Case

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Test {
        @Autowired
        private DaoLayer daoLayer;
            
        @org.junit.Test
        public void test()throws Exception {
             FavouriteWidgetInfo info=new FavouriteWidgetInfo();
             info.setGroupId(1);
             info.setReportId(2);
             info.setUserId(213);
             info.setTenantId(21);
             info.setApplicationId(2);
             daoLayer.createFavouriteWidgetInfo(info);  
    }
```

when i run the above test case the transaction should rollback because intentionally am throwing NullPointerException  which is a sub class of RuntimeException so my transaction should rollback when i enable spring transaction logs i can able see the rollback logging statements but when i look into the db the entity is persisted

Note:-
am using SpringSessionContext class spring implementation of Hibernate current_session context so creating the session will be managed by spring framework.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible situations:
The first:
If mysql does not support the storage engine, it will create a table with a MyISAM table, which is a non-transactional table. Generally modified to InnoDB
The second type:
Spring's AOP, declarative transaction management, defaults to rollback for unchecked exceptions. That is, by default, the RuntimeException() exception or its subclasses are rolled back; the checked exception, that is, the Exception can be caught by try{} and will not be rolled back. If you use try-catch to capture the thrown unchecked exception, it is not in the catch block. The page is hard-coded and the spring api is used to explicitly roll back the transaction, so the transaction will not be rolled back

I guess you used Exception in your controller, from the service layer to the controller layer, such as this statement
throw new Exception("xxxxxxxxxxxx");
Transaction is not rolled back

Hope your problem can be solved

Comment: i)am using mysql table which created in innodb engine. ii) here am not using any try-catch block inside the transactional method am throwing a NPE exception am propagating the exception to the caller which means spring proxy will detect that target class encountered some exception so that it should rollback but here rollback is not happening

Answer (score -1):

in your DaoLayerImpl you already saved the data into the Database before throwing NPE. If you want to throw error intentionally for testing purposes and don't want to save data in DB then remove 6 line from your code and put it in catch block or else delete.

the code should be like this.

```
class DaoLayerImpl implements DaoLayer
 @Transactional
 @Override
public Long createFavouriteWidgetInfo(FavouriteWidgetInfo favouriteWidget) {
    Session session=sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    //Long val= (Long) session.save(favouriteWidget); //remove this line.
    throw new NullPointerException();
    //return val;
}
```

The exception is ignored because you are using @Transactional annotation. And still want to rollback with then replace annotation with this **@Transactional( rollbackFor = Exception.class)**

Comment: my use case was to check the the transaction is working or not when you save the entity it will not directly saved on db it will get reflected once you commit the transaction please check what is transaction and how is it works

Comment: yeah, But I feel you might be committed and close the session after throwing the new exception. so, that's why said to remove the save method.

Comment: whenever you are using declarative i.e Spring @Transactional annotation spring will take care of handling transaction do dont want to explicitly commit or rollback the transaction

Comment: Yes because of the Annotation @Transactional this rollback is handled.

Comment: @Transactional internal exception handling is explained clearly [here](https://programmer.ink/think/transactional-rollback-problem-try-catch-nested.html).